# calculate wrong minute on 13th date in php function

Tags: php

I have one function that calculate minute on argument base

```
function calculate_time_date($argmnt1, $argmnt2)
{
    $to_time = strtotime($argmnt2);
    $from_time = strtotime($argmnt1);
    return round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2);
}
  echo calculate_time_date('13/05/2017 16:00', '13/05/2017 19:30');
  echo '<br>';
 echo calculate_time_date('12/05/2017 16:00', '12/05/2017 19:30');`
```

now this code give result `0` and `210` 
but i need 210 for both result, can you please help me what's i imrove in my function.

Comment: Why do you send the different dates?

Comment: You set date with incorrect format to strtotime. Must be `month/day/year` or `year-month-day`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **ignore the date** it you will only get the right minutes.

```
function calculate_time_date($argmnt1, $argmnt2)
{
    $to_time = strtotime(substr($argmnt2, -5));
    $from_time = strtotime(substr($argmnt1, -5));
    return round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2);
}
echo calculate_time_date('13/05/2017 16:00', '13/05/2017 19:30');
echo '<br>';
echo calculate_time_date('12/05/2017 16:00', '12/05/2017 19:30');
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the format to 13-05-2017 16:00 it is working fine

```
function calculate_time_date($argmnt1, $argmnt2)
{
    $to_time = strtotime($argmnt2);
    $from_time = strtotime($argmnt1);
   return round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2);

}
  echo calculate_time_date('13-05-2017 16:00', '13-05-2017 19:30');
  echo '<br>';
 echo calculate_time_date('12-05-2017 16:00', '12-05-2017 19:30');

 ?>
```